$\sin(x) \leq \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$ when $n$ is even and $x\geq 0$
Let $n\geq 2$ be an even integer and $x\geq 0$. I want to show that
$$\sin(x) \leq \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.$$
Assume first that $x\in (0,\pi]$.
By Taylor's theorem with Lagrange form of the remainder,  there is some $\xi\in (0,x)$ such that
$$\sin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} + \frac{\sin^{(2n+2)}(\xi)x^{(2n+2)}}{(2n+2)!}.$$
Since $n$ is even and $\xi\in [0,\pi]$,  $\sin^{(2n+2)}(\xi) = -\sin(\xi) \leq 0$, and the proof is over.
How can I deal with the case where $x>\pi$ ? Perhaps the following estimate holds:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\geq 1,$$
but I can't manage to show this even when $n=2$.

One can use Taylor's theorem, but the “remainder term” should be the term with $x^{2n+1}$, not the term with $x^{2n+2}$:
For even $n$ and $x > 0$ is, with some $\xi \in (0, x)$,
$$ 
\begin{align}
\sin(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{\sin^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k + \frac{\sin^{(2n+1)}(\xi)}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} \\
&\le \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{\sin^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k + \frac{1}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}
\end{align}
$$

My favorite approach and +1 there. I first found this technique in Hardy's A Course of Pure Mathematics.

This is a beautiful trick !

Observe that, $\sin x \leq x$, integrating both side over $(0,t)$, we get $$1 - \cos t \leq \frac{t^2}{2!} \implies 1 - \frac{t^2}{2!} \leq \cos t \leq 1.$$
Integrating both side again over $(0,x)$, we get $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \leq \sin x \leq x$
Integrating both side again over $(0,t)$, we get $$\frac{t^2}{2!} - \frac{t^4}{4!} \leq 1 - \cos t \leq \frac{t^2}{2!} \iff 1 - \frac{t^2}{2!} \leq \cos t \leq 1 - \frac{t^2}{2!} + \frac{t^4}{4!}$$
Finally after integrating both side again over $(0,x)$, we get $$x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \leq \sin x \leq x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}$$
Observe that even time integration gives $\sin x$ involving inequality, and odd time integration gives $\cos x$ involving inequality.
After $2n$ time integration, we will get, $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \leq\sin(x) \leq \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.$$
Similarly after $2n - 1$ time integration, we will get, $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} \leq\cos(x) \leq \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}.$$

My favorite way. I first saw this in Dorrie's "100 Great Problems of Elementary Mathematics", which I highly recommend.

Thanks @martycohen :-)

Also this book seems very exciting. Thank you for referring the book.

This answer has been transferred from here
We have $(\sin t)^{(2k+1)}=(-1)^k\cos t. $ Hence by the MacLaurin formula  with $ 4n+1$ we get for $x>0$ $$\sin x= \sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^{k}{x^{2k+1}\over (2k+1)!}+{x^{4n+1}\over (4n+1)!}\cos \zeta\\ \le \sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^{k}{x^{2k+1}\over (2k+1)!}+{x^{4n+1}\over (4n+1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k}{x^{2k+1}\over (2k+1)!}$$ Similarly for $4n-1$ we obtain
$$\sin x=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^{k}{x^{2k+1}\over (2k+1)!}+{x^{4n-1}\over (4n-1)!}(-\cos\zeta) \\
\ge \sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^{k}{x^{2k+1}\over (2k+1)!} -{x^{4n-1}\over (4n-1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k}{x^{2k+1}\over (2k+1)!} $$
